# WordPress page pointing to custom .php file but using Default Template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, url

A little hard to formulate the question here as I'm not sure what exactly is happening but I have a whole bunch of pages created in my WordPress installation. A good number of them are custom templates pointing to external for the WordPress PHP files. One of them though is definitely using the Default Template, however, every call to it points to external .php file with no apparent connection between the two.

To give a quick example, let's say the permalink for the page is '?page_id=100', again, using the default template. All calls to '?page_id=100' point to mycustomphpfile.php with no explanation why at this point. I've checked the default template and I've made a search for the page_id and the php file name throughout the whole project but no success.

The question I guess is how could you redirect the default template to point to an external .php page only for selected page_id numbers?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your default single_post template to have mini templates within the editable area of the content, and pull a special template depending on the category that the post is in.

same as how u get template parts, just put a if statement in front.

the other method is just naming your template correctly

read this page for more info.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy